# Restrict access to iframed domain through anything but its parent frame / domain

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, dns, seo, search-engine-bots

I have a site on one domain (say, iframedomain.com), which is loaded via iframe through another domain (say, parentdomain.com) and I want to prevent users from accessing it directly. How do I ensure that anyone attempting to access iframedomain.com get redirected to parentdomain.com without hindering SEO to iframedomain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue using this script here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/01/13/103518.aspx